# Headers also inserting into database while upload csv file data

Tags: mysql, csv

[image]

Here headers are also inserting into database .here uploading the csv file with comma separated data

```
   string Feedback = string.Empty;
        string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DataBaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString))
        {

            var copy = new MySqlBulkLoader(conn);
            conn.Open();
            try
            {
                copy.TableName = "BulkImportDetails";
                copy.FileName = fileName;
                copy.FieldTerminator = ",";
                copy.LineTerminator = @"\n";
                copy.Load();
                Feedback = "Upload complete";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Feedback = ex.Message;
            }
            finally { conn.Close(); }

        }
        return Feedback;
```

Comment: -1 for lack of effort. Pro tip - remove the first line of CSV.

Comment: You are being lazy, that's what. You saw the first line is wrong. So just remove it, don't go immediately ask on internet what's wrong, this isn't your personal debugging service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `NumberOfLinesToSkip` property to skip the first line, like so:

```
copy.NumberOfLinesToSkip = 1;
```

The use of this property is clearly shown in the documentation for `MySQLBulkLoader`. You must make a habit of reading the documentation to resolve your queries before you post a question here.